# How to make buttons behave correctly on items in a JQuery sortable?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, button, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a JQuery sortable with each item containing a button.  At the top of the page, I have an add button which adds items to the sortable.  I am trying to program the buttons on each sortable to replace the string on that specific item with the current user inputted value in the autocomplete (also at the top of the page).  Here is my code:

```
$(".addButton").click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
// set var item to be the string inputted by the user
var item = $("input[name='inputItem']").val(); //where 'inputItem' is the name of the <input>
// parses input string, splitting at commas into liArray containing substrings as elements
var liArray = item.split(", ");
// for loop to add each brew to the sortable list (length-1 because last element in array is empty string)
for (var i = 0; i < liArray.length-1; i++) {
    // sets var $li to the string in the ith index of liArray
    var $li = $("<li class='ui-state-default'/>").text(liArray[i]).append('<button class="replaceButton">Replace</button>');

    // adds var $li to gui
    $("#sortable").append($li);
};

$("#sortable").sort();

// refreshes the page so var $li shows up
$("#sortable").sortable("refresh");
```

});

Now that each item I add has a button with class = "replaceButton", I thought I could just declare in my .js something like this:

```
$(".replaceButton").click(function() {
    // set var item to be the string inputted by the user
    var item = $("input[name='inputItem']").val();  //where 'inputItem' is the name of the <input>
    // I DON'T KNOW WHAT TO DO HERE
});
```

I don't know where to go from there, as I dont know how to access the string of the specific item.  Would I use "this"?  Also would it be easier instead of just replacing the string, I deleted the specific item and created a new one in its place?  Thanks for any suggestions or answers you have!

Comment: So you are trying to access the most recently added list item?

Comment: not necessarily, The user will enter a string of 4 names in the autocomplete separated by ", ".  Then user will click the 'ADD' button putting the 4 substrings into their own (for a total of 4) items in the sortable.  Then the user will delete the autocomplete and put in one name.  I want the user to then be able to click on one of the 'REPLACE' buttons in the sortable and that specific item will get replaced with the name in the autocomplete.

Comment: Can you post the markup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you know that your button is part of your `li`, you are able to access the text like that:

```
// mind the dynamic event binding!
$('#sortable').on('click', ".replaceButton", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var item = $("input[name='inputItem']").val();

    $(this).parent()
          .text(item)
          .append( $(this).clone() );
});
```

You will have to append another instance of your replaceButton when you want to keep it.
And because you add buttons dynamically, mind the change in the event binding. I'm binding the click event to a container that is persistent and bind dynamically to all instances of `.replaceButton` even if they are not yet present.

Comment: You need to write `e.preventDefault();` at the start of the function. See my updated code.

Comment: Thanks for the help, just wondering what element I need to set their "id='container'", would it be each item of my list?

Comment: I changed it to your markup: `#sortable` will be ok, if it's present at page load.

Comment: It still just refreshes the page :/

Comment: copy again, forgot the `e` in the function statement. if it's still not working, please check if there are errors in the console.

Comment: awesome, works great :).  Just to clarify and so that I understand:
e.preventDefault() makes it so the default action is false.  the second line of code sets the var item to the user text in the autocomplete.  The $(this).parent().text.(item) goes to the button(this) then to the li(parent) then accesses the text and inputs the var 'item' then what? I dont know why the .clone is there?

Comment: `$(this).clone()` accesses the button (which is `this`) and clones it (maybe in this case it's not necessary, but it doesn't hurt) to append this clone to the `li` element. The original button gets killed together with the old text. Maybe you could directly append the button but I didn't know how an element behaves in this case.
by the way: I know, this will sound strange, but could you remove your upvote on my answer? I'm trying to achieve the "Unsung Hero" badge... I know, high end nerdy ^^

Comment: Ahh I see haha, it wont let me for the next 30 min, but I will when I can.  Thanks again for the help!

Comment: This is what it says: You last voted on this answer
52 mins ago
Your vote is now locked in
unless this answer is edited